# I have this Error Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

Tags: php, flutter, api, fatal-error

```
function dbExec($sql , $param_array){ 
    $database = new Database();
    $database->getConnection();
    $myCon = $database->conn;
    $stmt = $myCon->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($param_array);
    return $stmt;

}
```

Comment: my database file is :public function getConnection(){
        $this->conn=null;
        try{
         $this->conn=new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name , $this->username , $this->password);
         $this->conn=exec("set names utf8mp4");
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection Error" . $exception->getMessage();}}}

Comment: Please don’t post code blocks in comments. Instead, edit your original question

Comment: For the second code block posted, you are calling `exec` and setting that to `conn`, why? `$this->conn=exec("set names utf8mp4");`